# Getting 404 error while calling rest service methods in java(RestEasy)

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have designed a simple service to insert customer details to db and retrieve data from it. But when ever i am calling any service , i am getting 404 error.
I have provided my code below .
Customer.java

```
package com.fetch;

import java.io.Serializable; 
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer //implements Serializable 
{
@Id
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

public Customer(int id, String name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

MyAccount.Java

```
package com.fetch;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//@WebService()
//@Entity
@Path("user")
public class MyAccount
{
@POST
@Path("fetch")
//@WebMethod(operationName = "insert")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String insert(@QueryParam("name") String name) 
{
    try 
    {
       // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       // Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentinfo", "root", "root");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");


        String query = "insert into CUSTOMER"+"(NAME) VALUES"+"(?)";

        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1,name);
        st.executeUpdate();     
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return"Record inserted successfully";
}

@GET
@Path("retrive")
@Produces("text/html")
//@WebMethod(operationName = "retrive")
public String retrive() 
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String details = ""; 
    try 
    {
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentinfo", "root", "root");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");

        String query = "select ID,NAME from CUSTOMER";

        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        details = "<html><body>"; 
        details = details + "<table border=1>";
        details = details + "<tr><td><Strong>Id </Strong></td>" +
                                "<td><Strong>Name </Strong></td>" + "</tr>";
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            details = details + "<tr><td>" + rs.getInt("ID") + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + rs.getString("NAME") + "</td></tr>";
        }
        details += "</table></body></html>"; 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }   
    return details;
}
}
```

insert.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#call').click(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "rest/user/fetch", //this is my servlet
                data: "name=" +$('#name').val(),
                success: function(msg){      
                        $('#output').html(msg);
                }
            });
        });
        $('#take').click(function ()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: "rest/user/retrive", 
                        success: function(msg){      
                                $('#output').html(msg);
                        }
                    });
                });
    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<!-- <form action="rest/user/fetch" method="POST"> -->
    <p>
        Name : <input id="name" name="name" />
    </p>
    <input type="button" name="call" id="call" value="Insert"/>
<!-- </form> -->
<!-- <form action="rest/user/retrive" method="GET"> -->
    <input type="button" name="take" id="take" value="Retrive"/>
<!--  </form> -->
<p>
Response : <div type="text" id="output"></div>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>FetchAndInsert</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.fetch</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

JAR DETAILS:

```
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m02.jar
ojdbc14.jar
persistence-api-2.0.jar
```

Comment: What does 404 error mean in HTTP ?

Comment: rest - 404 Not Found or Bad Request

Comment: 404 only is Not Found, Bad Request would be 401.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the rest service started successfully with no failure in logs.
2. Have you included jersey API in jar list?
3. Are you calling the web service with proper URL? (ex: http:servername:portno/FetchAndInsert/rest/user/fetch with POST and http:servername:portno/FetchAndInsert/rest/user/retrive as GET)
4. Check if you would need POST or GET for fetch web service?
5. com.sun.jersey is the old API. You can use glassfish version.

Comment: I have provided the jar details too. Could you please check. Am i missing something ????